# Typescript Angular how to map an object of classes to a single entity

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, key-value

I have an array called panels.
It is setup like this

```
panels = [
    {
      active: true,
      name: 'Company Information',
      disabled: false,
      tempControls:[]
    },
    {
      active: true,
      disabled: false,
      name: 'Locations',
      tempControls: []
    },
    {
      active: true,
      disabled: false,
      name: 'Job Information',
      tempControls:[]
    }
  ];
```

I also have an object of objects that is setup like this

```
export class AssessmentModel{ 
   companyInformationModel? : CompanyInformationModel;
   locationInformationModels? :LocationInformationModel[];
   jobInformationModel? : JobInformationModel
}

export class CompanyInformationModel{
    companyName?:string = '';
    contactName?:string = '';
    primaryPhone?:string = '';
    secondaryPhone?:string = '';
    email?:string = '';
    hourlyRate? : string = ''
}
```

I need to map each object to that in the tempControls with the key of 'Name' and 'Value'
so the panels will look like this with tempControls initialized

```
panels = [
        {
          active: true,
          name: 'Company Information',
          disabled: false,
          tempControls:[
          'Title': '',
          'Value': ''
          ]            
        }
       ]

panels = [
    {
      active: true,
      name: 'Company Information',
      disabled: false,
      tempControls:[
       {
        'Title': assessmentModel.CompanyInformationModel."Nameofthefield" (example companyname is the first field inthe class"
        'Value': assessmentModel.CompanyInformationModel.companyName
       },
       {
        'Title': assessmentModel.CompanyInformationModel."Nameofthefield" (example contactname is the second field in the class"
        'Value': assessmentModel.CompanyInformationModel.contactName
       }
    ]},
    {
      active: true,
      name: 'Job Information',
      disabled: false,
      tempControls:[
      {
       'Title': assessmentModel.JobInformationModel."Nameofthefield"
       'Value': assessmentModel.JobInformationModel.JobTitle
      }
    ]},
     {
      active: true,
      name: 'Location Information',
      disabled: false,
      tempControls:[
      { 'Title': assessmentModel.LocationInformationModel[0]."Nameofthefield"
        'Value': assessmentModel.LocationInformationModel[0].address1
      },
      {
      'Title': assessmentModel.LocationInformationModel[0]."Nameofthefield"
      'Value': assessmentModel.LocationInformationModel[0].address2
      }]
     ,
     [
      {
      'Title': assessmentModel.LocationInformationModel[1]."Nameofthefield"
      'Value': assessmentModel.LocationInformationModel[1].address1
      },
      {
      'Title': assessmentModel.LocationInformationModel[1]."Nameofthefield"
      'Value': assessmentModel.LocationInformationModel[1].address2
      }
     ]
    }
```

So far I have (but of course this doesn't work)

```
ngOnInit(){
let model = _assesmentModel;
this.setPanels(model);
}

setPanels(model: AssessmentModel){
   this.panels.map(x => x.tempControls.map( y => y.Name = model.companyInformationModel.keys())
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use a class to specify the scheme, or would you also be happy with interfaces instead (`export interface AssessmentModel {...}`)?

Comment: Yea interfaces are fine too. I just used a class here